# How to serialize dictionary with custom value type for MongoDb?

Tags: c#, mongodb, dictionary, serialization

I have the following class, the instances of which I'd like to write to MongoDb:

```
public class ChartDefinitionBase
{
    public ChartDefinitionBase(ObjectId id, IDictionary<ISite, IExample> examples)
    {
        ObjectId = id;
        Examples = examples;
    }

    [BsonIgnoreIfDefault]
    [BsonId(IdGenerator = typeof(ObjectIdGenerator))]
    public ObjectId ObjectId { get; private set; }

    [BsonDictionaryOptions(DictionaryRepresentation.ArrayOfDocuments)]
    public IDictionary<ISite, IExample> Examples{ get; private set; }
}
```

When I attempt to call '`InsertOne()`' on an instance of this type, I get the following `ArgumentException`:

> GenericArguments[1], 'System.Collections.Generic.List{1}[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair{2}[System.String,System.Object]]', 
>   on 'MongoDB.Bson.Serialization.Serializers.ImpliedImplementationInterfaceSerializer{2}[TInterface,TImplementation]' violates the constraint of type 'TImplementation'.

If I convert the dictionary value type to a string, for instance, the exception disappears and serialization works great. However if I use a concrete implementation of `IExample`, I get the same exception.
How do I go about getting a dictionary with a custom value type to serialize?